# Designing difficulty, for overlapping ImageButton above two relative layout

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-imagebutton

I'm developing an application, For It's design I need something like overlapping ImageButton above two Relative layout or which layout it need to be.

[image]

Here comes the design that I implemented

[image]

Here comes the xml of the design I implemented

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/ll"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#fff"
android:gravity="center"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="10dp"
tools:context=".MainActivity">


<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="229dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relative_middle"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="1dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_back"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">



</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relative_middle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="323dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeLayout_base"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_back_white"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relativeLayout"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    tools:ignore="MissingConstraints">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="117dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="-19dp"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/linearLayout2"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/linearLayout2">

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:orientation="vertical">

                <ImageView
                    android:layout_width="64dp"
                    android:layout_height="64dp"
                    android:background="@drawable/circleshape"
                    android:padding="10dp"
                    android:src="@drawable/settings" />

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
                    android:text="Add"
                    android:textStyle="bold" />


            </LinearLayout>
        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

        <androidx.cardview.widget.CardView
            android:layout_width="110dp"
            android:layout_height="110dp"
            android:layout_margin="10dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:foreground="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground">

            // there are some codes here.

        </androidx.cardview.widget.CardView>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout_base"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="113dp"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_marginStart="0dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="0dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="3dp"
    android:background="@drawable/layout_back"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.888"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/relative_middle"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.962">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Now this design shows some issue like, Relative layout not fits as per screen size.

I'm using dpi drawables for implementing this design for all devices

My questions are

**1. How can I implement a ImageButton overlapping above two Relative layouts?**

**2. How can I implement this design that suitable for all device?**

Thanks

Comment: I would suggest look for FloatingActionButton example it will help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use FloatingButtons or Whenever you want to show some view over some other view put both views inside`FrameLayout` 
View at the last of `FrameLayout` will come above other views.
For more details 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/FrameLayout

Comment: Working with `FrameLayout` now. I hope this help